# Logic behind sizeof operator

Tags: c, operators, sizeof

Here we have `sizeof` operator in `C`. It is returning the size of datatypes,

```
printf("%d",sizeof(some datatype));
```

and result is 4 (OS dependent).

I want to know how it is calculating. what is the logic behind that operator.
If I ask you to write code for `sizeof` operator. what will be your answer?

Note : I want to know how `sizeof` written as a code so it is capable to calculate size.

As may be I am not able to ask my question properly,I am trying here again.

`Write one function which we can use instead of sizeof operator.`

Comment: This is not duplicate... I want to know how sizeof written as a code so it is capable to calculate size.

Comment: is there anyone who can take it a general question??? I wrote int for just as a example...

Comment: What code? `sizeof` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: @Krishna The implementation approach is perfectly well described in the accepted answer from the question which I linked - this is true for all types, not just int

Comment: If you want to know how `sizeof` is implemented, there are many C compilers with source freely available that you can use, not all of them complicated like GCC or clang.

Comment: check the followings


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171117/implementation-of-sizeof-operator


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938086/how-compiler-works-to-evaluate-sizeof-operator-in-c

Answer (score 5):

The compiler knows the size of all types, it has to or it would not be able to generate code correctly. This information is used by the `sizeof` operator.

Also note that `sizeof` is not some function being called at runtime, it's an operator that is fully evaluated during compilation.

Comment: Can you write the code if I ask you to develop one more sizeof operator with your name...I hope this will elaborate my question.

Comment: If you write `sizeof("Hello")` the compiler just replaces it with constant `6` - 5 letters plus the null character. As Joachim just wrote, it's a compile time operator, nothing is magically computed in runtime to know the size of something.

Comment: @Krishna I am pretty sure Joachim can :-) - essentially, it would result in something like `return 16`. This is what the compiler does - it looks up the type and since the compiler knows the length of each type it can replace it with a constant

Comment: note : Since C99 and variable length arrays, it is computed at run time when a variable length array is part of the expression in the sizeof operand.

Answer (score 1):

In the compilation time, `sizeof(int)` is replaced with a constant, specific to a platform.`sizeof` operator is completely implemented in the C compiler. It's not a function call, it's not working in a run-time.

The code for sizeof in the compiler would be pretty simple. It has hard-coded values that, for example, on 32 bit machine `int` has 4 bytes, `char` has 1 byte etc. So, it's just a simple look-up and replacement of string `sizeof(int)` with `4`.

By the way, you don't need parentheses on unary expressions, so having `int t[10]` you can just write `sizeof t`. However, you will need them for a type-name expression, for example: `sizeof(int)`. Just an interesting thing.

Comment: That's not correct. `sizeof int` is wrong, because `int` is a type name, not a unary expression. The things you can use as the argument to the `sizeof` expression are (1) a unary expression, or (2) a type name _in parentheses_. So if you have `int *foo[30]`, you can write `sizeof foo`, but you still have to right `sizeof (int)`.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson Ops, I made a mistake, thank you, I've edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof):

> In most cases, sizeof is a **compile-time operator**, which means that during compilation sizeof expressions **get replaced by constant result-values**.

Answer (score 0):

At compilation time `sizeof(int)` is replaced by appropriate size dependent upon the operating system(16 bit, 32 bit, 64 bit)

You can write your own size of function for strings

or a MACRO

```
#define SIZEOF(x) ((char*)(&(x) + 1) - (char*)&(x))
```